# How to get rid of the mongo IDs when converting a collection to json

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using the mongo java API to convert a collection to json:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("day_EURUSD");
FindIterable<Document> fi = coll.find();
System.out.println(fi.first().toJson());
```

However the outcome still contains nongoDB 'clutter':

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "565d90808b821237efdc39cb" }, "currencyPairs" : [{ "a....
```

How can I elegently get rid of _id and $oid so that i'm back to a 'normal' json?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("day_EURUSD");
    FindIterable<Document> fi = coll.find();
    fi.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
                    // Suppress the DB Id column of the query result.
               document.remove("_id");
        }
    });
    ...
```